# Gesture Up (swipe up) from the Navigation Bar android

Tags: android, navigation, gesture

How to handle up gesture from the android navigation bar?
It is essential that item appears when the gesture is made (with pressed at this time the finger on the screen).

Comment: Consult the [gesture documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Comment: Yes. But it does not give me the track from the navigation bar.
http://prntscr.com/c6dorg

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.accessibilityActionScrollUp){ // MANAGE THE UP BAR (return to mainActivity)

       NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

    }
```

Comment: Хм... Не знаю что тут, но я по другому реализовал. С рут правами, getevent и базибоксом.